# on blur in react is not closing my nav menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navbar

I am new to React and have a nav menu (.mega-menu-overlay) built in React that I am changing to be clickable instead showing/hiding via on mouseover and on mouseout. The function that previously worked to close the menu, when using onmouseover, is called handleMenuLeave(). Any insight as to what I am doing wrong would be great. My code is below:

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
      if (this.state.megaMenuContent) {
        if (window.scrollY >= 50) {
          window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            this.handleMenuLeave();
          });
        }
      }
      });
    if(document.querySelector('.mega-menu-overlay')){
        document.querySelector('.mega-menu-overlay').addEventListener('blur', () => {
            this.handleMenuLeave();
            alert('clicked');
        });
    }
  }
```

Comment: If `.mega-menu-overlay` is not a form element, button, or link, the `blur` event will not be triggered: https://jsfiddle.net/ss7nt69k/

Comment: Do you know how I can make it close using clicks on every other element?

Answer (score 0):

> on blur in react is not closing my nav menu

If `.mega-menu-overlay` is not a form element, button, or link, the blur event will not be triggered.

```js
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('blur', function(e){
 console.log(e.target.tagName)
})
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('blur', function(e){
 console.log(e.target.tagName)
})

document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('blur', function(e){
 console.log(e.target.tagName)
})
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('blur', function(e){
 console.log(e.target.tagName)
})
```

```css
div{
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:15px 0;
}
div:nth-child(odd){
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div>
hello world
</div>
<input type="text" />
<a href="#">Click me</a>
<button>
Click me
</button>
```

> Do you know how I can make it close using clicks on every other
>   element?

You can get every other element using a CSS selector such as `div:nth-child(odd)` and then attach an event listener to each element.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div:nth-child(odd)').forEach(function(div){ 
 div.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  this.style.display = "none"
 })
})
```

```css
div{
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:15px 0;
}
div:nth-child(odd){
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div>
First
</div>
<div>
Second
</div>
<div>
Third
</div>
<div>
Fourth
</div>
```

Comment: I meant every other element, as in... all elements on the page excluding the one we were discussing. I solved this by grabbing the event and then making the menu close onclick of every element except if the event tag name was not 'a'.

Comment: @sjw0525 then you should have said: all other elements -_-